# Authorize.net:- An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant

Tags: magento2.2.3, authorize.net, transaction, failure

I'm using **Sandbox Authorize.net** and everything working fine on one of my website which is in **Magento2.2.4** and currently this site is running fine with the autorize.net.

While on other site I'm using same details and this site is on **Magento2.3.1** but on this site i'm getting following problem on the checkout page:-

**"An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card."**

[image]

As i checked order get placed and order status is "pending" instead of "processing" and seems payment didn't process successfully.

**When i checked Merchant Mail then getting following:-**

```
Authorize.Net Developer Center Merchant,

Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results to it.
   Transaction ID: 60123298125
Transaction Result: This transaction has been approved.

The following message was displayed to the customer:

------------------------------An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

This transaction has been approved.

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

**Here is my sandbox authorize.net settings:-**

[image]

[image]

**Note1:-**  I think,we can run multiple websites by same **SANDBOX authorize.net** credentials so it won't be the problem.

**Note2:-**  Same settings and configuration is working fine on one of my M2.2.7 site.

Please help me as this is very urgent.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Please tell me if you have, I am also facing the same error.

Comment: don't know how but same configuration is working fine for me now...i'm using deprecated and it's now working fine.i used "Credit Card No.-370000000000002" and CVV "1234" later it's also working on "4242424242424242" with cvv "123".

Answer (score 0):

**This is Issue is Already post in Git**

[checkout with credit card issue (sorry but something went wrong message when checkout with credit card (Authorize.net)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9954)

**Solution  :-**

> - The problem was in script timed out when Authorize.net trying to post    transaction results to it.
> - Please check your .htaccess rules. I believe there are some rules    applied that blocked some core resources which is necessary for
>     payment transaction. You need to remove that rules (you may switch to 
>     default .htaccess of magento Magento 2.1.9)

Comment: I already went through this and increased timeout but wont work,.htaccess is fresh.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing the SSL certificate on the load balancer. After replacing this the error stopped and transactions started working normally and posting back to magento. There were no errors in the logs pointing to this being the problem, but it makes sense that this would cause a timeout issue. I hope this helps someone out since it took me 5 days to figure out that it was the SSL causing the problem.